# Using JS to enter text, but if I input text in one text box, the value already entered is getting deleted

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, shadow-dom

I have 3 text box in a row, and I am using JS to input the texts in the text boxes. But the problem is when I enter the text in one field, and go to second box to enter the text, the value from first text box is removed. we are using the below code to input text

```
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(
  "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')",
  element);
```

Comment: Any reason to use `JS` to alter `'value'` attribute rather `sendkeys()` for `text box`?

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB the application is built on shadow dom and sendkeys is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')"
((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(js, element);
```

> **Ensure that the before the second and third `text` is being pushed the `document.readyState == "complete"` is achieved.**