# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The error is:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

**The code is:**

```js
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","//Users//rozali//Documents//Selenium//geckodriver");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

//entering first name
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).sendKeys("testing it ");

//DOB
Select sel1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='month']")));
sel1.selectByIndex(4);

Select sel2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']")));
sel2.selectByValue("6");

Select sel3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='year']")));
sel3.selectByValue("2013");

//clicking sign up
driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_t")).click();
```

Comment: as your error states, `driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b")).sendKeys("testing it ")` looks like it's not interactable.  Go through your script step by step and see if it's showing, and accessible.  Is there an element overlaying it?

Comment: At first step it is showing the same error. I have check each line one by one but same error is visible every time.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard

`Element is not reachable by keyboard` in plain words means that the element can’t be reached using the keyboard, which means you won't even physically interact with it.

### Reason

There can be multiple reasons behind the error *Element is not reachable by keyboard* which can be either of the following:

- The element is **hidden**, as modern JavaScript-centric UI styles always keep the ugly raw HTML input field hidden. The `hidden` attribute could have been implemented through either of the following ways:
- A ***temporary overlay*** of some other element over the desired element.
- A ***permanent overlay*** of some other element over the desired element.
- Presence of attributes e.g. **`class="ng-hide"`**, **`style="display: none"`**, etc
- As per best practices while sending character sequence, you must not attempt to invoke `click()` or `sendKeys()` on any `<p>` or `<div>` tag; instead, invoke `click()` on the desired `<input>` tag following the [Official locator strategies for the webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890).

### Solution

There are different approaches to address this issue.

- Incase of ***temporary overlay***, use [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for the desired *element to be visible/clickable* as follows:

```js
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
        
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.nsg-button"))).click();
```

- Incase of ***permanent overlay***, use [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) interface as follows:

```js
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
        
String inputText = "Rozmeen";
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_b"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')"
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);
```

You will find a detailed discussion in [Using JS to enter text, but if I input text in one text box, the value already entered is getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453087/using-js-to-enter-text-but-if-i-input-text-in-one-text-box-the-value-already-e/47459466#47459466).

- Incase presence of attributes e.g. **`class="ng-hide"`**, **`style="display: none"`**, etc., use [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from the [JavascriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) interface to edit and reset the **`style="display: none"`** attribute to **`style="display: block"`** as follows:

```js
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';");
```

You will find a detailed discussion in [Can't fill in the Hidden text area element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831039/cant-fill-in-the-hidden-text-area-element/47832218#47832218).

### References

- [For input[type=file], should allow sendKeys even when display=none](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1173)
- [Special-casing file upload controls in keyboard-interactability check](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1230)
- [Element  is not reachable by keyboard](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1184)
- [Input field with display: none is not interactable at all?](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1150)

---

### This particular issue

If you look into the *HTML* of *Facebook* login page, the application contains [**React**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) [**Native**](http://www.reactnative.com/) elements. So an element once represented with `id` as **u_0_b** in your system may not be represented by the same `id` as **u_0_b** in the next run on your system. Hence, we have to take the help of *Dynamic Locator Strategy*. You can use the following code block to perform your intended steps:

- Code Block:

```js
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstname' and contains(@class,'inputtext')]")).sendKeys("testing it ");
//DOB
Select sel1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='month']")));
sel1.selectByIndex(4);
Select sel2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='day']")));
sel2.selectByValue("6");
Select sel3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='year']")));
sel3.selectByValue("2013");
//clicking sign up
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@name='websubmit' and contains(.,'Sign Up')]")).click();
```

- Browser Client:

[image: FacebookRegistration]

---

### Update

Addressing the error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not
> reachable by keyboard

has become easier with the availability of Firefox capability [moz:webdriverClick](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/#mozwebdriverclick)

### moz:webdriverClick()

Through **`webdriverClick()`**, you can pass a boolean value to indicate which kind of interactability checks to run when performing a click or sending keys to an element. For *Firefoxen* prior to **v58.0**, some legacy code as imported from an older version of [FirefoxDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver) was in use. With the availability of **Firefox v58**, the interactability checks as required by the [WebDriver specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) are enabled by default. This means that geckodriver will additionally check if an element is obscured by another when clicking and if an element is focusable for sending keys. Because of this change in behaviour, we are aware that some extra errors could be returned. In most cases, the test in question might have to be updated so it conforms with the new checks.

To temporarily disable the WebDriver conformant checks, use **`false`** as value for this capability.

**Note**: This capability exists only temporarily, and it will be removed once the interactability checks have been stabilized.

Comment: Hi, how about chromedriver please? I've tried above webdriver.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable), presentOfElement etc, but no luck. I also tried JS view.

Comment: Maybe disabling CSS would be easier?

Comment: Temporary or permanent overlays will not get you a ElementNotInteractableException. You will get the error message that talks about tried to click on X but Y element was in the way. Most of this answer is incorrect or contains misleading information.

Comment: @JeffC I think you are a bit confused here. I would suggest you to have a look at the _Browser Architecture_ and how CSS works. That would clear your basic doubts. Let me know if you need further help on any of those topics or directions.

Comment: Nope... not confused at all. When you set up the scenario described here and try it for yourself, you'll see that it's not correct too.

Comment: i had style.display='none' and this code helped me:

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';");


thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can try this **code**:

```java
public class Rozmeen{
    
    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Automation\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);
            driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
            
            //entering first name
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("pagelet_bluebar"))));
            driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("testing it ");
            
            //DOB
            selectFromDropDown(driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_day")), "4");
            selectFromDropDown(driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_month")), "Jun");
            selectFromDropDown(driver.findElement(By.name("birthday_year")), "2013");
            
            //clicking sign up
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.name("websubmit"))));
            driver.findElement(By.name("websubmit")).click();
        }

       
        
        public static void selectFromDropDown(WebElement element , String Visibletext){
            Select select = new Select(element);
            select.selectByVisibleText(Visibletext);
        }
}
```

try out this code and let me know the status.

Comment: i tried using the wait commands but still it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the use cases I had the same issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element <div id="search"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

using id for identifying an element before sending keys. Something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("search")).sendKeys("...");
```

After testing I changed to CSS Selector and it solved the issue:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#search > input:nth-child(2)")).sendKeys("...");
```

So, I highly recommend to use different methods to interact with the elements, because something else can save your time solving problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is also an issue by using name/id like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("99999999");
```

Instead of this, use Xpath. This solved the issue for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='load_form']/input")).sendKeys("Java");
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar error on a button when the `click()` operation was performed:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException Exception

As mentioned by DebanjanB in his answer, the element was not reachable by keyboard.
To solve this, I replaced `click()` with `sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)`, and the button got clicked.

Comment: No: pressing a keyboard key is a different thing to clicking a mouse button - that't the whole point. Check carefully if the (simulated) input device doesn't matter!

Comment: @AmigoJack In my case, the simulated input device didn't matter, only the CTA had to be invoked.