# Selenium - Element is not reachable by keyboard - trying to input a date

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement sdate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'dateOfServiceInput')]"));
sdate.sendKeys("20180531");
```

Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: You could just set the elements value property.

Comment: Another solution should be, in Chrome, inspect the element...that should open the `Elements` tab in the Chrome Developer Tools, with the element highlighted...right click on the highlighted element and choose `Copy -> Copy Xpath`...now paste that xpath into your `By.xpath` instruction....profit

Comment: Chech this discussion [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160)