# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error while sending text to Email field on Quora using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

user = "someemail@email.com"

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/browser/")

browser.get("https://www.quora.com/")

username = browser.find_element_by_name("email")

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

username.send_keys(user)
```

Here is the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

I think there is another thread with a similar issue. Either the solutions in that thread didn't work for me or I don't know how to implement the solutions.

Comment: find by name return multiple elements you can try with different locators like 
"ID".

Comment: try out the answer given below, and let us know if any one of them worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
find_element_by_name("email")
```

is present multiple times in DOM. So that wouldn't work.

You can try with this **css selector** :

```
input[class*='header_login_text_box'][name='email']
```

**Code :**

```
username = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[class*='header_login_text_box'][name='email']")

username.send_keys("user@gmail.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Email** field within **Login** section of [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.quora.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='title login_title' and text()='Login']//following::div[1]//input[@class='text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction']"))).send_keys("someemail@email.com")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: quora_email]

Comment: This worked like a charm for a clicking a link within a popup after clicking a link on a webpage! +1 Nothing else I was trying was working.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, the locator used returning two elements and required element is second one. driver trying to interact with first element, so exception is throwing.

good see in console, the locator returning required one or not.

```
> $$("[name='email']") (2) [input#__w2_wD9e9Qgz12_email.text, input#__w2_wD9e9Qgz18_email.text.header_login_text_box.ignore_interaction]
> 0: input#__w2_wD9e9Qgz12_email.text 1:
> input#__w2_wD9e9Qgz18_email.text.header_login_text_box.ignore_interaction
> length: 2
> __proto__: Array(0)
```

go for another locator, if not able to figure it out another locator, then comment, will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver

user = "someemail@email.com"

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/browser/")

browser.get("https://www.quora.com/")

username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='text header_login_text_box ignore_interaction' and @type='text']")

browser.implicitly_wait(10)

username.send_keys(user)
```

Here You can find Why [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by) occurs.

Comment: The id you have given is not static and that's a dynamic. For me your ID is not working, I'm sure this wouldn't work for OP as well.

Comment: @cruisepandey Done. Update answer with proper xpath.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the `Select` aproach like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
```

try this

```
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '''//*[@id="ReportViewer1_ctl04_ctl07_ddValue"]''')))).select_by_visible_text(str(x))
```

Comment: Looks like you're also calling on the `expected_conditions` module...did you forget an import statement?