# Selenium won't type to textarea and raises ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

This is the HTML code in question:

```
<textarea rows="1" cols="1" name="text" class=""></textarea>
```

This is my code:

```
msgElem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[name='text']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", msgElem)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'Whats up mate, how you doin';", msgElem)
msgElem.submit()
```

The code executes and nothing happens. I assume it selects the textarea but doesn't type nothing into it? or nothing happens at all. It also finds the element so I assume I don't need to wait for the textarea to be visible.
When I don't use js and just do

```
msgElem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[name='text']")
msgElem.send_keys('Whats up mate, how you doin')
```

It gives me ElementNotInteractableException.

Comment: add real URL for this HTML adn create minimal working code so we could run it and see problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
ElementNotInteractableException
```

...implies that the *WebDriver* instance was unable to interact with the desired element as the [Element was Not Interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397).

---

### Analysis

The [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) which you have used actually identifies two elements within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) and the parent element of the first matching element contains the attribute **`style="display:none"`** as follows:

```
<form action="#" class="usertext cloneable warn-on-unload" onsubmit="return post_form(this, 'comment')" style="display:none" id="form-dyo">
    <input type="hidden" name="thing_id" value="">
    <div class="usertext-edit md-container" style="">
        <div class="md">
            <textarea rows="1" cols="1" name="text" class=""></textarea>
        </div>
```

Hence you see [ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55945497/elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not-interactable-error-while-s/55946833#55946833).

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequesce* to the desired element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.title + div textarea[name='text']"))).send_keys("Sowik")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='message']//following::div[1]//textarea[@name='text']"))).send_keys("Sowik")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```