# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error while clicking on youtube search button using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, youtube, css-selectors

I'm using latest python and latest Selenium chrome webdriver. I'm trying to have a simple code to search in youtube but I'm getting the below error. Can anyone help me?

```
File "search.py", line 8, in <module> searchBox.click()
Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

CodeStartsHere:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
if searchBox.is_enabled():
    searchBox.click()
    searchBox.send_keys("youtube test")
    searchButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]/yt-icon')
    searchButton.click()
else:
    print("What the heck")
#CodeEndsHere
```

Answer (score 1):

To initiate a search within https://youtube.com you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://youtube.com')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='search_query']"))).send_keys("youtube test")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button#search-icon-legacy>yt-icon").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://youtube.com')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='search_query']"))).send_keys("youtube test")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='search-icon-legacy']/yt-icon").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: youtube_search]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable when clicking on an element using Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55235367/selenium-common-exceptions-elementnotinteractableexception-message-element-not/55236397#55236397)
- [Selenium won't type to textarea and raises ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984794/selenium-wont-type-to-textarea-and-raises-elementnotinteractableexception/61986216#61986216)

Answer (score 0):

I found 3 elements with your tag on Youtube homepage, the 1st one is invisible, the 2nd one is the search field which you are trying to reach.
Use this tag:

```
"//div[@id='search-input']"
```

Comment: Thank you for quick help, changed code as per your suggestion:  

searchBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="search-input"]')

But still hit with this error. 

File "search.py", line 9, in <module>
    searchBox.send_keys("youtube test")
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable