# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"btnk"}

Tags: python, selenium, session, module, sendkeys

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\m\Desktop\python\selen\chromedriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

I am trying this simple code to open google, search something with the above code. But I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m\Desktop\python\selen\auto.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 496, in find_element_by_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"btnk"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: try this :-https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078324/4513879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That should be solved your problem :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("https://google.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("google search through python")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(4)
driver.quit()
```

I tested in Ubuntu + chrome browser

Replace your code

```
driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Automation")
driver.find_element_by_name("btnk").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

To =>

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("google search through python")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have a question, is it possible to do web scraping with selenium too? I must read the content of a web page and do some calculations on them, then filling some fields on that web page.

Comment: Please give a tutorial link or code for that purpose if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Official python selenium documentation link 
 https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Comment: For web scraping, you must learn beautifulsoup, scrappy or lxml, with the help of this library, you can easily scrap web page.
if you want to scrap dynamic web content like ajax, jquery request, need to learn selenium with these libraries.