# Not able to select dropdown in MS Edge; getting an ElementNotInteractableException error message

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge

I'm not able to select dropdown value in Edge using Selenium. Getting the below error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: The command failed because the specified element is not pointer or keyboard

I'm getting the error message in Microsoft Edge version 18.

Comment: Please include the code that's causing this error.

Comment: Hi TylerH, I have added the code below                                                              
select = new Select(select_Bill_State);
select.selectByVisibleText(Ohio);

Comment: When i am using scrollIntoView function from java script  executor I am able to select the element succesfully

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ElementNotInteractableException is caused when an element is found, but you can not interact with it.There could be several reasons for this:

1. The element is not visible / not displayed
2. The element is off screen
3. The element is behind another element or hidden
4. Some other action needs to be performed by the user first to enable it.

So, please check whether the dropdown is hidden, and make it visible and available. More detail information about this error, you could check this thread:

[org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by)

[How do I resolve the ElementNotInteractableException in Selenium WebDriver?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resolve-the-ElementNotInteractableException-in-Selenium-WebDriver)

Besides, here are some related article about how to Select Value from DropDown using Selenium Webdriver using Java, you could check it: [link1](https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html) and [link2](http://learn-automation.com/handle-dropdown-in-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: When i am using scrollIntoView function from java script  executor I am able to select the element succesfully