# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable while inserting value using Selenium and Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to insert a value into a text box located in a web page.

Text box appears at the bottom of the web page and the element is not locatable by the code.  I should **Inspect** two times to see the table value in Chrome (first time it shows a different/parent HTML all together) that suggests us that there are multiple layers and requires finding in deep.

I've tried inserting the string as shown below..

```
driver.find_element_by_id("arid1005").send_keys("TESTING")
```

and

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("arid1005")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "TESTING";',elem)
```

I've also tried finding the elements by **Class Name, CSS, Xpath** but end up getting

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

When I inspect 2 times, the below table gets highlighted.

```
<table class="SearchBarInput" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr><td width="">
<textarea style="width:99%;height:21px;" class="sr" cols="" wrap="off" rows="1" id="arid1005"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Can somebody throw some light on what I'm missing here?  Sorry if this question was already asked but I couldn't find any relevant so far.

Comment: Is there any iframe?

Answer (score 0):

The *id* attribute of the desired element looks dynamic, so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.SearchBarInput>tbody>tr>td>textarea"))).send_keys("TESTING")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='SearchBarInput']/tbody/tr/td/textarea"))).send_keys("TESTING")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- References: You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

  - [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni/46601444#46601444)
  - [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160)

Comment: If your element is not in the scope of the displayed page, as you said that element is in the bottom. Then first thing you should do is to scroll down the page so that element is in the scope of the displayed page.

Comment: @nvntkmr Scrolling implicitly happens with EC as `element_to_be_clickable ()`

Comment: @DebanjanB, that didn't work for me, unfortunately.  I'm getting **selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:** with no message.  When I actually click on the Advanced search, it gives me the **SearchBarInput** in a different frame.  But I actually can't find any frame element for that.  Any idea?

Comment: @DebanjanB, also when i try to copy the CSS selector or Xpath, it's not the same as what you've given.  Am I missing something?  :(