# How to click a dynamic 'like' button using Selenium through Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

Hi~in this music websit:
[Music website link](https://www.xiami.com/list/song?id=51009&type=all)
i want to click on the like button in the right side of the song bar
i use below  codes:

```
like_number=3
like_pos=f'#app > div > div.content-wrapper > div.song-list-view.list-view.view-without-leftbar > div.song-list > div > div.table.idle.song-table.song-list-table > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child({str(like_number)}) > td:nth-child(5) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div'
button = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(like_pos)
self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
ActionChains(self.browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()
```

But,there is no response,console shows that my the tag is not interactive:

```
element not interactable” exception
```

I am so confused ,cause i search for whole the stack overflow ,but there is no practical solution for me

I just want to achieve a simple function of clicking on like button
Thanks if you have any great idea for me!

The hard thing is that you have to pause you mouse for a while and then click button shows ,so that you are able to click on it ,this is so wired situation.

Below is image example

[image: image: Song bar activate when you move your mouse and pause for a while]

[image: image: The state when you click on the like love button]

Comment: How about putting sleep after the mouse is moved over the button? Maybe it need some time to react?

Comment: You probably need to move to some element that you can see first on the row, like the time or song title, and then you can click on the like button. Theory being that if the element isn't visible it might have not have a location and selenium doesn't know how to move to it.

Comment: Try to use Xpath way rather than Css way, i don't know why ,but it is practical.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the `Like` button in the right side of the song bar you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  driver.get("https://www.xiami.com/favorite/88955424")
  ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr//div[@class='duration-container ops-container']")))).perform()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table/tbody/tr//div[@class='duration-container ops-container']//div[@class='operations ops-right']/div[@class='ops-item']/div[@class='iconfont']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: like]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to resolve ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not visible in Selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868009/how-to-resolve-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-visible-in-seleni/46601444#46601444)
- [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160)

Comment: Yeah，I know, it can be done in Xpath, but it cant be done in Css,if you try to replace it with Css with right place, no response, maybe my original try is right but use Css, so wired...