# Can't make this search on a webpage with python using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, scrape

I'm running the following script to make a search for books on this webpage:

```
from selenium import web-driver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#going to a website
driver.get("https://pacobello.com.br/")

#print the page title
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_name("s")
search.send_keys("Saramago")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

#quit a tab
#driver.close()

#quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Comment: Hi Thiago! Check my answer and let me know if it worked !

Comment: Please go through the below link let me know if it helped.
[There was same kind of query and it is been addressed detailed in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPATH instead:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
```

Therefore the complete code will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

#going to a website
driver.get("https://pacobello.com.br/")

#print the page title
print(driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text']")
search.send_keys("Saramago")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

#quit a tab
#driver.close()

#quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: @ThiagoOliveira Please consider also to vote up if you like :) it would help a lot ! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

install 83 version of chrome not 84

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: it worked just fine changing the driver. Do you know why it happens? My chrome version is 84.

Comment: Because your chrome version is 83, You can check from your chrome settings.