# SendKeys is injecting the text to the input field only for a few seconds and immediately after that the text vanishes from the input field

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to end a text to the input field named City (HTML code is mentioned below) using

```
driver.findElement(By.id("City")).sendKeys("Brussels");
```

The script runs and inserts the city as Brussels for few seconds and then the value 'Brussels' vanishes immediately. The script then errors out with the message

****Exception****
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

***HTML Code****`<input class="form-control input-block-level form-text required"  id="City" autocomplete="new-password" data-validator="validateFieldText"  data-errorfield="cityError" onblur="validate(this)" onfocus="focusField(this)"  data-drupal-selector="edit-city" type="text" name="City" value="" size="60" maxlength="128"  placeholder="City" required="required" aria-required="true">`

Comment: I would read the accepted answer on this related post, it details what this exception can be generated by, as well as other solutions to get around the exception using the `webdriver` - (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by), I personally have found using the `JavascriptExecutor` to be my favorite way to circumvent `selenium` exceptions and set values to hidden elements or elements which were out of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically from what Ryan said you can use either of the following two solutions depending on what the issue is. Due to your element not being interactable.

```
Webdriver wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("City"))).sendKeys("Brussels");
```

Or using Javascript executer.

```
String inputText = "Brussels";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("City"));
String js = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+inputText+"')"
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, myElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the page to get loaded fully. once the element is loaded correctly, may be then try to  enter text into the text page.