# Selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable in ionic framework

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, ionic-framework

Python script:

```
userId_box =driver.find_element_by_id("userId")
userId_box.send_keys(usr)
```

Inspect element:

```
<ion-input class="passwordinput sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md hydrated" placeholder="User ID" id="userId" type="text" value=""><ion-icon class="eye md hydrated" role="img"></ion-icon><input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" aria-labelledby="ion-input-0-lbl" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" maxlength="3" name="ion-input-0" placeholder="User ID" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Error:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: I hope this answer will solve your problem. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by)

Comment: Thank you ,Now ,It' interactable but I have facing these issue now "userId_box.send_keys(usr)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'".I have given userId and Password but it's not taken.

Comment: Can you try to click first then send_keys.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try explicit wait
2. Sometimes pausing the program also helps
3. Sometimes the element is not in view and you have to scroll to the element in order to interact with the element. You can also try that using JavascriptExecutor