# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element is not reachable by keyboard error sending text to input field using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Opens Firefox webbrowser
browser.get('https://protonmail.com/') # Go to www.protonmail.com website
loginButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 > ul > li:nth-child(8) > a') # Finds login button
loginButton.click()  # Clicks login button
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # wait until the site has fully loaded

usernameElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#username') # Finds login element for email/username
usernameElem.send_keys('firstName.lastName@protonmail.com') # Enters email

passwordElem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#password') # Finds login element for password
passwordElem.send_keys('password') # Enters password # Enters password
```

This code crashes at the following line:

```
usernameElem.send_keys('firstName.lastName@protonmail.com')
```

The error message is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="username" class="w100 inputform-field"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I would like to understand, what the problem is first. I give the browser time to load. What is the reason for this error? And second: how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872160/16136190) help?

Comment: Thanks, but I am not familiar with JavaScript. Solutions using python are preferable.

Comment: In that case, I think you can use [`WebDriverWait`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait until some conditions are satisfied, using [`ExpectedConditions`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). So, the code that combines both would look like: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.*(attr))).click()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<input>` field have a ancestor `<label>` as:

```html
<label class="inputform-container w100 inputform-container--bigger" for="username">
```

Snapshot:

[image: for_username]

---

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```py
  driver.get("https://protonmail.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.action>a[href='https://mail.protonmail.com/login']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='username']"))).send_keys('firstName.lastName@protonmail.com')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```py
  driver.get('https://protonmail.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='action']/a[@href='https://mail.protonmail.com/login']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='username']"))).send_keys('firstName.lastName@protonmail.com')
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```py
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: protonmail_username]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not reachable by keyboard: while sending text to FirstName field in Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by/49872160#49872160)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I pasted the imports you suggested and your code using the CSS_SELECTOR strategy but I still get an "is not reachable by keyboard"-error at the line of code, where the user email should be putted in. I saw your screenshot...did you manage to get it exactly with that code you suggested?

Comment: Yesterday the solution worked just perfecto with ChromeDriver/Chrome combo.

Comment: Ok, I am using Firefox...does it work also with this one with your code?

Comment: The code is pretty generic and should work cross browser.

Comment: I have found the mistake: you must not attempt to invoke click() or sendKeys() on the <label> tag, instead invoke click() on the desired <input> tag following the Official locator strategies for the webdriver (I have found this on the link you provided me). Maybe you could update your answer then I can mark your answer as solution...Thanks!

Comment: Please don't get me wrong :) the other one is also my answer and I've provided the reference for your correspondence. The solution may vary as per the error you see. In this usecase, the solution I've proped is tested in Chrome. However I'm yet to check on Firefox.