# Java: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getPath() when loading image-url from resources

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have task writing auto test, when i should upload file from resources. And when I run code:

```
 WaitService waitService = new WaitService(driver);
        AddTestRunPage addTestRunPage = new AddTestRunPage(driver);
        WebElement fileUploadElement = waitService.waitForExists(By.id("libraryAttachmentsAddItem"));
        String pathToFile = PositiveTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/download.jpeg").getPath();
        fileUploadElement.sendKeys(pathToFile.substring(1,pathToFile.length()));
        addTestRunPage.getButtonSubmit().click();
        Assert.assertEquals("download.jpeg",addTestRunPage.getLabelUploaded().getText());
```

I have error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getPath()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null

Help, please. How I can resolve it?

I also tried absolute path, but i have the same error

Comment: Have you tried`String pathToFile = PositiveTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("download.jpeg").getPath();`

Comment: Try `String pathToFile = PositiveTest.class.getResource("/resources/download.jpeg").getPath();`

Comment: @sweintritt With this code I have error: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: @g00se With this code I have error:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getPath()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null

Comment: OK. In that case, @sweintritt has the right path

Comment: The `ElementNotInteractableException` is not related to the resource. This must be coming from `fileUploadElement.sendKeys(...)`. See if this fixes your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864965/org-openqa-selenium-elementnotinteractableexception-element-is-not-reachable-by

Comment: @sweintritt When I add code: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("libraryAddAttachment"))).click(); instead of WebElement fileUploadElement = waitService.waitForExists(By.id("libraryAttachmentsAddItem"));  I have red color  on the 20

Comment: And I have error on the 'sendKeys'

Comment: But your original problem ist solved. I suggest you open a new question for this problem, with more detailed information about your project. Preferably a minimal example which creates the error.