# Send keys fills form to slow (Python + Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Is there something faster I can use to fill forms since finding id's and sending info via .send_keys takes like 10 seconds for 7 fields. I'm using this currently but its way to slow for what I need it to do, thanks for any help.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_billing_name']").send_keys("John Doe")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_email']").send_keys("supreme@gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_tel']").send_keys("012-345-6789")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='bo']").send_keys("439 N Fairfax Ave")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_billing_city']").send_keys("Los Angeles")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='order_billing_zip']").send_keys("90036")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nnaerb']").send_keys("1111222233334444")
```

Comment: Is the delay in sending the keys, or in finding the elements?  Try temporarily removing the `.send_keys(...)` from these calls and see if that makes a noticeable difference.

Comment: @JohnGordon how can I test that? I'm able to grab item I need and size in under 2 seconds when finding elements however the checkout page just takes long. Even when sendkey is typing it's very slow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem a few hours ago. Instead of `send_keys()` use

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('idName').setAttribute('value','text_to_put');
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect and very fast. I tried to do the same method for drop down menu select but that didn't work as well haha. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure but I would assume you would click it first then try to `.click` the right option, have not tried it though

Comment: Just to clarify - this is for finding an element faster, not for making send_keys faster (when much input is used). Also, does this method support XPATH finding?

Answer (score 0):

To fill the form fields quicker you can use induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and then use `execute_script()` as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  text_to_insert = "John Doe"
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '" + text_to_insert + "';", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#order_billing_name"))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  text_to_insert = "John Doe"
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '" + text_to_insert + "';", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='order_billing_name']"))))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to change angular element text/value using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69982660/unable-to-change-angular-element-text-value-using-selenium-and-python/69986243#69986243)
- [How to combine execute_scipt and WebdriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57747480/how-to-combine-execute-scipt-and-webdriverwait/57749372#57749372)
- [Using JS to enter text, but if I input text in one text box, the value already entered is getting deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453087/using-js-to-enter-text-but-if-i-input-text-in-one-text-box-the-value-already-e/47459466#47459466)