# How to combine execute_scipt and WebdriverWait

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I wonder if there is a way to combine `execute_script()` and `WebdriverWait`. Currently I have the following code:

```
network_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="folder_box"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 4)
try:
    wait_network_list = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'network_list')))
except:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", network_list)
```

The code does what it's supposed to do, but I guess this is a ugly way. Is there a way to combine my try and except statement to one line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke [*WebdriverWait*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) within [`execute_script()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method as follows:

```
try:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='folder_box']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]"))))
    print("Element was clicked")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Element wasn't clicked")
    break
```